# MaskedInput with two masks same field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask

I have an element and I want to be able to attach 2 masks to it. If the length of the field is smaller than 11 I want one mask to be in place and another otherwise. The problem is that whenever I call the "mask" function it moves the caret to the begiining and I cant keep typing:

```
$("input[name=cpf_cnpj]").on(
    "keydown",
    function(){

        if ($(this).val().replace(new RegExp("(-|\\.|/|_)","g"),"").length < 11){
             $(this).mask("999.999.999-99");
         }
         else{
            $(this).mask("99.999.999/9999-99");         }                       
        }

);
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: wait, you are replacing input on each keydown.. remove that, and only count the length like: `$(this).val().length`, then add appropriate mask, and on input `blur` or `focusout` do replacing! do you get what I mean? that replacing is I guess what moves caret

Comment: thanks my friend, I get what you mean but I like the effect of while typing the mask be shown cause it helps adding the symbols like . and -.